# Printing text with number returned from function in one print statement on the same line in Lisp

Tags: printing, lisp

I have a very simple question. How can I have a piece of text and an integer value returned from a function to be printed on the same line?
I am using a language called Lisp

```
(defun factorial (n)
  (if (= n 0) 
      1
      (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))

(print "Factorial ( 7 ) is ")
(print (factorial 7))
```

This code prints

```
"Factorial ( 7 ) is "
5040
```

How can I have both of them print on the same line?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`princ` instead of `print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm)
or, better yet, [`format`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_c.htm):

```
(format t "Factorial ( ~:D ) = ~:D~%" 7 (factorial 7))
```

prints

```
Factorial ( 7 ) = 5,040
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, I am completely new to this language. How can I get that format statement to say "Factorial ( 7 ) is " instead of what written there? @sds

Comment: You should just play with the code and read the docs, the minor tweaks like that should be quite within your reach.